# Добавить возможность выполнять код в сниппете для других языков (не только JavaScript)

Tags: предложение, сниппеты

Заметил, что для javascript есть компилятор, а для java нет. Почему бы не прикрутить такой - чтоб консоль хотя бы была. Это будет очень удобно для отвечающих по этому языку.

То же можно сделать и с другими популярными языками.

Comment: А чего именно джава? Я вот больше хочу питон и плюсы. И шарп ещё.

Comment: @Qwertiy "То же можно сделать и с другими популярными языками."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На enSO Мете [много раз](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358746/1991579) вопрос [поднимался](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327744/1991579).

По сравнению с JS очень сложно всё это реализовать.

- В случае с тем же C++ поведение различных компиляторов может отличаться.
- Для Java и т.п. для полноценной работы нужен сервер, а это лишняя нагрузка + дыра в безопасности.
- В компилируемых языках может уходить много времени на компиляцию, в то время как JS интерпретируемый и выполняется прямо на клиенте.

Comment: А как же сторонние сервисы? Есть же сайты, на которых можно производить онлайн компиляцию. Разве у них нет такого - "вставьте тег с ссылочкой и у вас все будет"?

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar я никогда особо не интересовался, как такие сайты это делают. Вероятно, там просто на js интерпретатор какой-то написан. SE таким не будет заморачиваться, при условии, что они и базовые то фичи медленно делают.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, зачем там интерпритатор? Там просто песочница на сервере, в которой запускается с урезанными правами прога.

Comment: @Qwertiy чтобы сервак не грузить, а делать всё на клиенте. Т.е, вся логика на js, которая лишь эмулирует java.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, сомнительная идея.

Comment: Ну есть же компиляция в WebAssembly, для .NET - Blazor, так что это не так уж сложно на сегодняшний день. На Microsoft Docs, например, через Blazor сделали онлайн запуск примеров кода на .NET языках (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netcore-2.0#instantiating-a-string-object) Более весомым аргументом, на мой взгляд, было бы то, что это не очень полезно. Запускаемые примеры на JS хороши тем, что позволяют продемонстрировать реальную работу с веб. А на С++/C# таким образом только базовую работу со стандартной библиотекой и консолью можно будет продемонстрировать...

Comment: @Qwertiy http://teavm.org/sandbox/index.html вроде не отправляет запросов на сервер